# A description of all continuous functions on the quotient space.

Tags: general-topology, functions

Is there any method which allows us to describe all continuous functions (maps to $\mathbb{R}$) on the quotient space?

For examle, how could I classify all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}/[x\sim2x]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can classify them easily: these are the constant functions, whatever Hausdorff topological space $Z$ they land in.

If $f:\mathbb{R}/[x\sim 2x]\longrightarrow Z$ is continuous, then
$$
g(x):=f(\bar{x})
$$
is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ by composition with the canonical surjection $x\longmapsto \bar{x}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\mathbb{R}/[x\sim 2x]$.

Then for every $x$
$$
g(x)=g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\ldots=g\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)\qquad\forall n\geq 1.
$$
Letting $n$ tend to $+\infty$ and using continuity at $0$, we get
$$
g(x)=g(0)\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
So $g$, hence $f$ is constant.

The converse is clear: every constant function on the quotient space is continuous.

Comment: The sequence converges to $0$, so the constant sequence $g\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)$ converges to $g(0)$. That does **not** mean $g(x)=g(0)$. It would also imply that the identity is constant, which is absurd.

Comment: @StefanH. If the constant sequence $g(x/2^n)$ converges to $g(0)$, this means it is constant equal to $g(0)$... With or without bold characters.

Comment: No, it depends on the topology. It could be that every neighborhood of $g(0)$ contains $g(x)$ if the space is not $T_1$.

Comment: @StefanH. Ah, right, thanks. I'll add Hausdorff. I wanted to generalize and I overlooked that.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I overlooked the OP was asking for maps to $\mathbb R$. Then your answer is of course correct, provided the topology assumed is $T_1$.

Comment: At least this shows that the quotient space is not $T_1$, if that's of interest.

Comment: @StefanH. And this also proves that I haven't considered a non Hausdorff space in a long time...

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y=X/\sim$ be a quotient space equipped with the quotient topology. $f:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if $f \circ \pi$ is continuous, where $\pi:X\to Y$ is the natural quotient map. The reason is $U\subseteq Y$ is open in the quotient topology if and only if $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: You can get the composition operator, $\circ$, with `\circ`.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that your quotient is describe by a relation $\rm R$. Then the **Universal Property** of the quotient topology tells you that there is a bijection $$ \text{ continuous functions on } \mathbb R/\mathrm{R} \longleftrightarrow \mathrm{R}-\text{invariant continuous functions on } \mathbb R.$$

Where $\rm R$-invariant means that $f(x) = f(y)$ when $x \sim_{\rm R} y$.